# Generating matrices on imputed data for use with elastic net

Tags: r, matrix, glmnet, r-mice

After using `mice` to create 50 imputations of my dataset, I am keen to use the package `glmnet` to run an elastic net. I understand that the appropriate way to analyse imputed data is by applying the `with` and `pool` functions to the `mids` object created when `mice(x,...)` is run, but `glmnet` requires its data to be fed as a matrix. Both `model.matrix` and `build.x` can be used to convert a generic data frame to a matrix. The `mids` object can be converted to a data.frame; however, using the available data as a single dataset would appear to undermine the whole imputation process.

**Example:**

```
df <- mice::nhanes
imp <- mice(df) #impute data
com <- complete(imp, "long", TRUE) #creates data frame
mat <- build.x(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, com, contrasts = FALSE)
```

Assuming the imputations are accurate, what is the most appropriate way to preserve the imputations and create the relevant matrices for use in `glmnet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use my [glmnetUtils package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=glmnetUtils), which implements a formula/data frame interface for glmnet. Then fit your elastic net like with any other R model-building function.

```
install.packages("glmnetUtils")
library(glmnetUtils)

# ... do whatever is required to create an analysis data frame ...

glmnet(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, data=com)
```